# Calculate week before

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that is populated with info once a week, with the date when it is populated as a single column in the table.

I am working on a query that basically compares data from this week against the data from last week exclusively, therefore I need to know which week was last week. This is easy to accomplish in the following way:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED, 'IW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'IW') -1
  AND TO_CHAR(LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED, 'YY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')
```

The table may contain data from several years, therefore I also check that the year be the same.

The problem comes when we are in the first week of the year and we want to compare against the previous week. This way we are in week 1 minus 1 it gives us 0, but I want it to compare against week 54 from LAST year.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I feel that the TRUNC function might work with this but I am unsure as to how to use it in this scenario, also keeping in mind that it should not compare against the same year but last year.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be picky there wasn't a week 54 last year. But you should use IYYY (or at least IY) if you're using IW, otherwise you can get weird results. 2016-01-01 is 1653 with YYIW and 201653 with YYYYIW; but 1553 with IYIW and 201553 with IYYYIW. (And 1601 with YYWW and 201601 with YYYYWW if you prefer; just be consistent).

Answer (score 6):

I'd avoid using TO_CHAR in this event altogether ... stay within DATE format ... safer, especially when breaching years ..

```
 where trunc(LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED,'IW') = trunc(sysdate-7,'IW')
```

That single condition should give it to you :)

You can see what it's doing here:

```
    1  with w_data as (select sysdate-level d from dual connect by level <= 20 )
    2  select d, trunc(d, 'IW') w
    3* from w_data
  SQL> /

  D                    W
  -------------------- --------------------
  09-feb-2016 13:20:41 08-feb-2016 00:00:00
  08-feb-2016 13:20:41 08-feb-2016 00:00:00
  07-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  06-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  05-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  04-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  03-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  02-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  01-feb-2016 13:20:41 01-feb-2016 00:00:00
  31-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  30-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  29-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  28-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  27-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  26-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  25-jan-2016 13:20:41 25-jan-2016 00:00:00
  24-jan-2016 13:20:41 18-jan-2016 00:00:00
  23-jan-2016 13:20:41 18-jan-2016 00:00:00
  22-jan-2016 13:20:41 18-jan-2016 00:00:00
  21-jan-2016 13:20:41 18-jan-2016 00:00:00

  20 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare with a date a week ago, by using `sysdate - 7`, and combine with a single value:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED, 'IYYYIW') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 7, 'IYYYIW')
```

Notice I'm using the IYYY year model to match the IW one, otherwise you'd get odd results.

But as @ditto shows it's cleaner to use TRUNC with the IW format mask. And as @MaxU pointed out truncating the source column will prevent indexes being used, unless you have a matching function-based index. You can avoid that by modifying Ditto's approach slightly:

```
WHERE LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7, 'IW')
AND LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW');
```

As a demo:

```
with lastweek(date_generated) as (
  select sysdate - level from dual connect by level <= 50
)
SELECT LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED
FROM LASTWEEK
WHERE LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 7, 'IW')
AND LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW');

DATE_GENERATED
--------------
2016-02-07    
2016-02-06    
2016-02-05    
2016-02-04    
2016-02-03    
2016-02-02    
2016-02-01
```

Or to see the year change, lets go back further, again just as a demo:

```
with lastweek(date_generated) as (
  select sysdate - level from dual connect by level <= 50
)
SELECT LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED
FROM LASTWEEK
WHERE LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 42, 'IW')
AND LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED < TRUNC(SYSDATE - 35, 'IW');

DATE_GENERATED
--------------
2016-01-03    
2016-01-02    
2016-01-01    
2015-12-31    
2015-12-30    
2015-12-29    
2015-12-28
```

Answer (score 1):

the query from Ditto will work, but it will not use indexes on "LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED" column, because of applied function (trunc), so i would go for the following:

```
select
    next_day(to_date('2016-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd')-14, 'MONDAY'),
    next_day(to_date('2016-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd')-14, 'SUNDAY')
from dual;
```

Output:

```
12/28/2015        01/03/2016
```

So your query would be:

```
WHERE LASTWEEK.DATE_GENERATED
between next_day(to_date('2016-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd')-14, 'MONDAY')
and next_day(to_date('2016-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd')-14, 'SUNDAY')
```

Comment: Good point about the indexes, but bear in mind that the day names have to be in the current session's NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE which can make it more fragile than it looks. Also using between will only be safe if the `date_generated` always has its time set to midnight - otherwise records after midnight on Sunday will be missed.